# Derivation of EL equations for real scalar field

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-calculus

I am looking to derive Eq. (1.11) from these notes on QFT from Tong’s notes: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/one.pdf

But Im the second equation, is there not suppose to be a factor of 1/2 when the derivative of the Lagrangian is taken?

Comment: Consider to include the relevant equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the Lagrangian is quadratic in $\partial_\mu \phi$. When you have $\frac12 \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi$, $\partial^\mu \phi$ still depends on $\partial_\mu \phi$, but it's not as straightforward. The simplest way is to write the kinetic term as

$$T = \frac12 \eta^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu \phi$$

and then when we calculate the derivative there are two ways to do so, cancelling the $1/2$:

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial (\partial_\alpha \phi)} = \frac12 \eta^{\mu\nu} (\delta^\alpha{}_\mu \partial_\nu \phi + \partial_\mu \phi \delta^\alpha{}_\nu) = \partial^\alpha \phi.$$

Or, if you prefer, just write it out:

$$T = \frac12 (\partial_t \phi)^2 - \frac12 (\partial_x \phi)^2 - \frac12 (\partial_y \phi)^2 - \frac12 (\partial_z \phi)^2$$

and you can see plainly that the factors of $1/2$ go away.

Comment: Thank for you this. Could you please explain the first derivative calculation a bit further?

Comment: @ThomasMoore What part specifically? The whole thing is a first derivative calculation.

Comment: Actually, your derivation is very helpful. I went through it just now by hand again. I can see it now, thanks!